# C#, Fired access violation when use HeapAlloc from kernel32 in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dll, access-violation

I've an x.dll created compiled to **`.NET Standard 2.1`**, When I reference this library to .NET framework console, desktop application worked successfully, but when I reference this library to .NET Core 6 console application I got an error:

***System.AccessViolationException.  Attempted to read or write protected memory.
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.***

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
public static extern int GetProcessHeap();

[DllImport("kernel32")]
public static extern void* HeapAlloc(int hHeap, int flags, int size);

private static int _heap = GetProcessHeap();

public static void* Alloc(int size)
{
    void* result = HeapAlloc(_heap, 0x00000008, size); // <--- Exception
    if (result == null) throw new OutOfMemoryException();
    return result;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: It is the standard way such code fails.  Not on the first call, but some call later.  When the code has written too much into the allocated heap block and corrupted the heap.  There is no guarantee such code consistently fails.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your response, But I get error at first call and app crashed

Comment: .net6 generates 64-bit code by default, which does make this code fail.  GetProcessHeap() returns a handle, IntPtr in C#.  Do favor Marshal.AllocHGlobal()

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, I changed cpu type to x86 and worked successfully.